# PowerPoint Online Bug

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-js, officedev

When viewing a slideshow in PowerpointOnline created with add-in, slides containing add-in’s content do not appear to load. Error message

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXtFY.jpg)

I think this error is a bug of PowerPoint Online.I have created the other apps, that are already in MS Store market. They work without errors in read mode, but bring the same error in full screen mode. Please, look at this screen video:
yadi.sk/d/mtypZZx-wNSst 
yadi.sk/i/coV_DWvQwNUTf

I think there is a problem with  using sharepoint Add-in files with PowerPoint Online for all webservices in fullscreenmode.

It's really bug or it's my error?

Manifest text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ContentApp">
  <Id>9136e827-53ab-4d0c-852a-05e9d3d1bdd1</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>PROJECT</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="PROJECT" />
  <Description DefaultValue="PROJECT DESCRIPTION"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="URL" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="URL" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="URL" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>URL</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>URL</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="URL" />
    <RequestedWidth>1000</RequestedWidth>
    <RequestedHeight>600</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: I tried the link to see your video but got a not found message. I also tried a random content add-in from the store (E.g. multiple choice quiz and poll everywhere) and it worked ok for me.  Could you share the name/id of the add-ins you say that error out (already on the store)?

Comment: Humberto, hello. Please check this links, I have downloaded video to youtube. https://youtu.be/fVtG79tFAjY and https://youtu.be/ttfyVIFWnE0 Errors appears with share point add-ins  (http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online) with every service, that are already on the store.  Now we try to submit our add-in and add it to store, but MS testers use share point add-in, faces with that error and reject submission.

Comment: Humberto, unfortunately its MS Powerpoint Online BUG(( please check - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc9d9488-e591-4166-a1a3-93c9ac321fa4/powerpoint-online-bug?forum=officegeneral#666aa975-ad0e-49e6-94f2-57cb410fba23. And you have inconsistency inside Microsoft about this. We are trying to accept our Powerpoint Add-ins, and place it at the Office Store. But MS testers rejected our request because of this errror twice. I hope you will repair the communications about this error inside MS and we will see our Add-in in MS Store ASAP